# Probability density function of random variables.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I need help with one of my study guide questions. We learned a bit about PDF but I am not sure how to combine them. Here is the problem:
[image]

Could anyone walk me through how to do this? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Since the random variables are independent, $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$ Then, it is possible to determine the pdf of $u$ and $v$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. First step: You should recognize that the above functions are pdfs of normal random variables.
2. Second step: Determine the parameters of the normal distributions. For the random variable $X$ they are $μ_Χ=1$ and $σ_Χ^2=2$.
3. Third step: Use the fact that the sum (or difference) of independent normal random variables has again the normal distribution (but with different parameters $μ, σ$).
4. Fourht step: Use the fact that $$E[X\pm Y]=E[X]\pm E[Y]$$ for every $X,Y$ and $$Var(X\pm Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$$ for **independent** random variables $X,Y$ to calculate the mean and the variance of the random variables $U,V$.

Your result should be $$U \sim \mathrm{N}(μ_U=μ_X+μ_Y, σ^2_U=σ^2_X+σ^2_Y)$$ and $$V \sim \mathrm{N}(μ_V=μ_X-μ_Y, σ^2_V=σ^2_X+σ^2_Y)$$ (Note: the plus in the variance of $V$ is not a typographical mistake).

Comment: More generally, it is true that for a finite collection of independent RVs $X_i\sim \mathcal N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ one has $\sum_i a_i X_i \sim \mathcal(\sum_i a_i \mu_i,\sum a_i^2 \sigma_i^2)$

Comment: Stefanos, thank you for the valuable hints! I will be following these steps and posting my results.

Comment: @Stefanos, I have shown my work below. Let me know if my method needs changing.

Comment: @Stefanos I posted another tricky question to do with statistics. You did an awesome job of answering this question last time I had a study guide and was wondering if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

@Stefanos Here is what I got. Did I go in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks nice! good work! Add, that adding up or subtracting independent normal random variables, gives you again normal random variables, so you only need to calculate the parameters as you have done :)